# Proper/alternative method to recover lost directory (ext4)

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, data-recovery, ext4

**Disk / Filesystem structure:**

Seagate 1TB > LUKS > LVM2, Ext4

**Scenario:**

While running a script which uses youtube-dl to download a complete channel, disk become full and **base directory ("/Downloads"), was emptied and its file/directory permissions were set from "drwxr-xr-x" to "-rw-rw-r--"** - which I don't really understand why. A couple of new files were added afterwards before I finished the process when realised something wrong was happening.

**Solutions I've tried:**

First thing I did was to make an image of the disk, which I've processed with **TestDisk (deep search) with no success since it doesn't recognize the directory as such**, I guess it just see it as a file, not a directory, because I simply can't open it as I can with any other directory.

Afterwards, I've used Photorec, and I've got near 500 directories with about 500 files each one, where I guess are all the lost files. Indeed, I've found among them some important PDF files which I've searched, but since files names, structure and attributes are lost, I believe it's impossible to find and restore the 95% of sub-directories and files in a reliable way.

**At this point:**

The disk shows now >300 GB of free memory, so I assume there is not an extra solution as simple as change the directory permissions back to "drwxr-xr-x", because those files and subdirectories - that memory space to be precise - has been freed, but still, Is there any alternative or possible solution to try to recover/restore most of the files **and their structure**?

Comment: You can use `debugfs` (see `man debugfs`) to interactively examine the `ext4` structure. This requires good knowledge how the filesystem works (inodes, journal, directory format), so invest a few days to read up on that. Also, start from a fresh copy of the disk (I hope you either kept the original copy or the untouched harddisk around); photorec may have found files, but may also have lost information. Your goal is to look at the journal and see if you can figure out what happened when the disk became full, and recover the contents of Downloads. It's not going to be easy...

Answer (score 0):

The article
[Recovering deleted files in Ubuntu with ext4 filesystem](https://gist.github.com/ebautistabar/cca12863e6335d08a019f015f53fac4a)
describes how one user recovered his deleted files:

- Open a terminal and make a copy of the filesystem journal:

  ```
    sudo debugfs -R "dump <8> /opt/sda6.journal" /dev/sda6
  ```

  `/dev/sda6` stands for your device. Don't store the copy in `/tmp`.
- Install ext4magic:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install ext4magic
  ```
- Get to a root shell through Grub boot > Advanced options >
  recovery mode > Enable networking.
  This may take some time.
- When the menu appears again, it should say something like
  "read/write mode" at the top. Choose the "root shell" option.
- In the root shell enter `umount /home`
- To list all files use:

  ```
    ext4magic /dev/sda6 -a $(date -d "-6hours" +%s) -f user/folder -j /opt/sda6.journal -l
  ```
- To recover the files:

  ```
    ext4magic /dev/sda6 -a 1332606716 -f user/folder -j /tmp/sda6.journal -r -d /opt/RECOVER
  ```

  where:

  - `-r` will recover files that were marked as 100% in the
    previous output
  - `-d` is the directory to store the recovered files.
- Exit from the shell and select the "resume" option in the menu.
  Delete unwanted files.

Comment: What does 1332606716 mean in the command?

Comment: @Hackeron: This is explained in the link.

Comment: -a 1332606716 means "after unix timestamp 1332606716" (Sat Mar 24 2012 16:31:56 GMT)